# Select all checbox next to input type

Tags: jquery

This question was asked in interview. I have to check all checkboxes between first `input [type=text]` and  next `input[type=text]`. both input type text will do the same thing.

```js
$("input[type=text]").keypress(function() {

  console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
  $(this).next("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked',true);
  //$(this).nextUntil("input[type=checkbox]","input[type=text]").attr('checked',true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">
<input type="text" placeholder="enter something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">

<input type="text" placeholder="enter something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
    
</div>
```

Comment: add class to all check box and do `$(".class1").attr("checked","checked")`;

Comment: I have to do it without class.is it possible.same thing was asked me by interviewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$("input[type=text]").keypress(function() {

  console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
  $(this).nextUntil("input[type=text]").prop('checked',true);

});
```

To be more explicit, if element other than checkbox is set:

```
$(this).nextUntil("input[type=text]", ":checkbox").prop('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should try this.

```js
$("input[type=text]").keypress(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil("input[type=text]").attr('checked', true);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">

  <input type="text" placeholder="enter something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">
  <input type="checkbox" name="something">

</div>
```